# How to select element based off specific parent structure in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a script that will get the grab the  only if the parent structure is div.main-element input+label+ul.

**Is there any appropriate way to set that up using javascript or jquery?**

If anyone could direct me to the **appropriate answer** or **documentation** that would be absolutely awesome.

My end goal would be to replace the ul>li with an hr tag using either an append or .replace()

here is my **HTML**:

```
<div class='main-element'>
    <input>
    <label></label>
    <ul>
        <li>Example</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class='main-element'>
    <input>
    <label></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the element that you want exists using this kind of code in jquery :

```
if($("div.main-element ul li").length){
//your code
}
```

This will execute on your html example, next you can modify the value of the first element using :

```
$("div.main-element ul li").append("blahblahblah");
```

Note that this gives you access to the first li tag found inside of a div.main-element>ul of your html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a second argument to a jquery call that is the parent container within which you want to get elements from. There is also a `find` function that does the same thing.

HTML:

```
<div class='main-element'>
    <input>
    <label></label>
    <ul>
        <li>Example</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class='secondary-element'>
    <input>
    <label></label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $secondaryElement = $('.secondary-element');
var $secondaryInput = $('input', $secondaryElement);
```

Another approach:

```
var $secondaryInput = $('.secondary-element').find('input');
```

Both of the examples above will return ONLY the input element inside of the `secondary-element` div.

Does that answer your question?

Links:

https://api.jquery.com/find/

and

https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context

Answer (score 0):

This will get all elements with your composition and replace ul>li by hr.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".main-element input+label+ul li");

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var parent = elements[i].parentNode.parentNode;
    var ul = elements[i].parentNode;
    ul.parentNode.removeChild(ul);
    var hr = document.createElement("hr");
    parent.appendChild(hr);
}
```